# How to combine status change event with the user action

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, callback

I am using one third party js library for VoIP features. This library is based on the WebSocket events to connect, disconnect, making a call, etc.

Now, the problem is to bind the status event with the action.

For example, here is the code to connect to the VoIP server

```
var VoIP = create({
        call: {
            callDefaults: {
                sendInitialVideo: false
            }
        },
        logs: {
            logLevel: "SILENT"
        },
        authentication: {
            subscription: {
                server: "spidr-ucc.genband.com"
            },
            websocket: {
                server: "spidr-ucc.genband.com"
            }
        }
    });
```

In order to listen to the events let's say for a connection, there is an event listener

```
VoIP.on("call:stateChange", function (params) {



});
```

and on the HTML page there a button, on which if a user clicks, APIs try to make the connection.

```
<button id="makeConnection" value="connect" />

$("#makeConnection").on("click",function(){

     doConnect();

});

function doConnect(){

  VoIP.connect({
          username: username,
          password: password
 });
}
```

Now, I want to program it in such a way that when a user clicks on a button, it will call `VoIP.connect` API and returns the status as a `callback` or `then`.

So, inside `$("makeConnection")` function I want something like, which makes the connection and returns the status so that I don't have to manage the state change and make connection action differently.

```
doConnect().Onstate(function(status){


});
```

Comment: How often does `call:stateChange` fire? If multiple times, you cannot use a promise. (Or wait until the first event only - for which there should be something like a `.once()` method next to `.on()`)

Comment: call:stateChanges called multiple time for different or same events for example, if we make a call it gets fire, if we put a call on hold it gets fire. I tried promise but as you said it gets fires only once.

Comment: Yes, in that case promises are not an option for you. Have a look at my answer below which should allow the call that you imagine. Notice however that you shouldn't repeat `doConnect().Onstate(…)` call now, as otherwise that would install multiple event listeners on the same `VoIP` instance.

Comment: Actually all events flow through the `stateChange` hence i guess we need to isolate the VoIP.on so that for other events like in call , on hold it does not get re register

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have `doConnect` return an object with the `onState` method that you want to call:

```
function doConnect(){
    VoIP.connect({
        username: username,
        password: password
    });
    return {
        onState(callback) {
            VoIP.on("call:stateChange", callback);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: how about the unregistering event once it gets fired?  like ` VoIP.on("call:stateChange", function(){ $(this}.off(); callback(););`

Comment: @Hunt Given that you haven't linked the VoIP documentation, I didn't know you could do that. Sure, then even a promise approach is possible, if all you want to do is wait for the first event.

Comment: here is the link of SDK that we are using `https://kandy-io.github.io/kandy-link-js-sdk-3.x/docs`